# Get data from variable "Users" and put data in fields in Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this script from Google Developer site that fetches all the domain users:

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'wter.se',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
      }
    } 
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

I would like to get each users parameters and add them to a spreadsheet.

The variable users have all these parameters (users.EmailAdress etc), but how do i put them in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build an array of arrays (a 2D array) with one array for each row in the sheet, here is an example with 3 columns that list all the users of my domain using the simple [UserManager class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/user-manager).

The code structure is pretty much the same, a for loop and `users[i]` properties...
 The output array here is called 'r' and is written in the sheet using the final `setValues(r);` - the code has also a sorting function that you don't need but I left it here for info if ever someone needs it.

```
function listUsers(s) {     
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getDataRange().clear()
  var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
  var r = new Array();
  var f = new Array();

  for( var i = 0 ; i < users.length ; i++ ){
    var Umail = users[i].getEmail(); 
    var UnomF = users[i].getFamilyName()
    var UnomP = users[i].getGivenName()

    r.push([UnomF,UnomP,Umail]);
  }   
  r.sort(function(x,y){
    var xp = x[0].toLowerCase();
    var yp = y[0].toLowerCase();
    return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;//  sort on name ascending
}
        )
  var header = ['Nom de famille','Prénom','Email']
  sheet.getRange(1,1,1,r[0].length).setValues([header]).setFontWeight('bold')
  .setBackground('silver').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);
  sheet.getRange(2,1,r.length,r[0].length).setValues(r);
}
```